# Is there a Steiner system $S(13,15,25)$?

Tags: combinatorics

Lottery switched its main game this year to a draw of $15$ balls out of a pool of $25$,  is there Steiner system for $S(13,15,25)$ or other ?

Tia

Comment: According to Wikipedia, “As of 2012, an outstanding problem in design theory is if any nontrivial (t < k < n) Steiner systems have t ≥ 6.” So your question is much harder than an outstanding problem. If I were you I wouldn't count much on it being answered here.

Answer (score 2):

We have a set a $25$-element set $S$ and a family $\mathcal{F}$ of $15$-element subsets of $S$ such that any $13$-element subset of $S$ appears in exactly one $T \in \mathcal{F}$.

There are $$\binom{25}{13}=5200300$$ $13$-element subsets of $S$ and any $15$-element subset of $S$ contains $$\binom{15}{13}=105$$ $13$-element subsets of $S$.

Hence $$|\mathcal{F}|=\frac{\binom{25}{13}}{\binom{15}{13}}=\frac{148580}{3},$$  which is not a whole number, giving a contradiction.  So no Steiner system with these parameters exists.